# Using singular or plural verb after "Not only does it.."

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

In the sentence, "Not only does it present associates with a unique opportunity but large bonus as well.", would I put "present" or "presents"?

Comment: You're mixing up too many problems, all of which would be better addressed somewhere like English Language Learners.

Your example does not depend on "present" or "presents" but almost everything else in the sentence.

Briefly, you needed "It presents associates not only with a unique opportunity but also with a large bonus (as well)."

Are those differences clear?

Comment: There is no option of singular vs. plural. In "does it present", "present" has to be in the "plain form" because it is an infinitive. The auxiliary "does" is what is conjugated for singular vs. plural. The plural form would be "do they present".

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence makes use of a correlative, NOT ONLY . . . BUT(ALSO). 
The rules about correlatives are something like this.

- Words after correlatives(each constituent ) should be some what balanced

*Both the conjoined subjects if singular, verb should be singular, if plural verb plural.

- If either is plural, the subject closer to the verb , gives its person and number to or agrees with the verb.

In the example there is an "Emphatic DO" which takes the person and number of another "Impersonal IT", serving its anaphoric or introductory function.

It dissuades us from using PRESENTS. There is yet another issue.  NOT ONLY . . . BUT ALSO can join words and phrases, besides sentences. Here phrases are linked. Place " does" after " it "and place "NOT ONLY" any where suitably, and discover the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a correlative conjunction requires balance between the phrases being modified. I would phrase this as follows (in agreement with Barid's suggestion):

It does present associates not only with a unique opportunity but also with a large bonus.

Or: It presents associates not only with a unique opportunity but also with a large bonus.

The word "also" makes "as well" redundant.